# Cannot resolve type error in simple auth scala, play framework project

Tags: scala, playframework

I have following code

```
package controllers

import play.api.mvc._

/**
  * Provide security features
  */
trait Secured {

  /**
    * Retrieve the connected user's email
    */
  private def username(request: RequestHeader) = request.session.get("username")

  /**
    * Not authorized, forward to login
    */
  private def onUnauthorized(request: RequestHeader) = {
    Results.Redirect(routes.Authentication.index)
  }

  /**
    * Action for authenticated users.
    */
  def IsAuthenticated(f: => String => Request[AnyContent] => Result) = {
    Security.Authenticated(username, onUnauthorized) { user =>
      Action(request => f(user)(request))
    }
  }
}
```

And

```
package controllers

import javax.inject.Inject
import play.api.i18n.MessagesApi
import play.api.mvc.Controller
import service.userService
import views._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

class Restricted @Inject()
(userService: userService,
 val messagesApi: MessagesApi) extends Controller with Secured {

  /**
    * Display restricted area only if user is logged in.
    */
  def index = IsAuthenticated { user =>
    _ => userService.getUser(username).map {
      Ok(views.html.restricted(user))
    }.getOrElse(Forbidden)
  }

}
```

But I can't compile that, it keeps failing on views.html.restricted(user) with Type mismatch, expected: String => Request[AnyContent] => Result, actual: String => Request[AnyContent] => Any. I'm super new to scala and play and after few hours of googling I couldn't find anything similar to my error.

Comment: Assuming `userService.getUser` returns an `Option` or similar monad, the `map` method requires a function parameter. Try `.map { _ => Ok(views.html.restricted(user)) }` instead.

Comment: Indeed it does return Option[User], your advice didn't help. I've tried to solve it withOk(views.html.restricted(user.get)), but then getOrElse isn't working. Maybe something is wrong with IsAuthenticated function?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix this issue by changing return type of userService.getUser from option[User] to User and adding try/catch to handle if None is found.